# How can we write our own custom AT commands?

Tags: unetstack

Is there a way that we can write a custom AT command for unetstack/subnero modems ? I refered [Chapter 12](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_at_script_engine.html) but could not find this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT command shells (and Groovy shells) can be extended with shell extensions.  Shell extensions implement a [`org.arl.fjage.shell.ShellExtension`](http://org-arl.github.io/fjage/javadoc/org/arl/fjage/shell/ShellExtension.html) tag interface. Static methods (and attributes) of the shell extension class are made available in the shell as commands (and variables/constants). In the AT command shell, they are called using AT commands as briefly described in [section 12.3](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook.html#_at_script_engine) of the Unet handbook.

For example, the handbook shows an example of loading the `PhysicalShellExt` via:

```
AT~EXT=org.arl.unet.phy.PhysicalShellExt
```

On loading this, static methods of this class become accessible using AT commands. For example, methods:

```
  static def plvl() {
    // code to get power level here
  }

  static String plvl(float p) {
    // code to set power level here
  }
```

are accessed as:

```
AT~PLVL
AT~PLVL=-3
```

respectively.

Comment: Is node info service accessible with AT commands ?

Comment: Yes. Just add the shell ext: `AT~EXT=org.arl.unet.nodeinfo.NodeInfoShellExt` and then access the parameters (e.g. `AT~NODE?`)